# JSON Schema Draft 7 issue in validating required property in array object

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this JSON Schema file (shrinked to not show stuff not related to the question) :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "urn:jsonschema:testing:frmwk",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The root schema",
  "default": {},
  "required": [
    "processOrder"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "processOrder": {
      "$id": "#processOrder",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The processOrder schema",
      "default": [],
      "additionalItems": true,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$id": "#0",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The first anyOf schema",
            "default": {},
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "properties": {
              "cleanHistory": {
                "$id": "#cleanHistory",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The cleanHistory schema",
                "default": {},
                "additionalProperties": true,
                "properties": {}
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$id": "#3",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The fourth anyOf schema",
            "default": {},
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "properties": {
              "processEvents": {
                "$id": "#processEvents",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The processEvents schema",
                "default": {},
                "required": [
                  "identityTrigger"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": true,
                "properties": {
                  "identityTrigger": {
                    "$id": "#identityTrigger",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The identityTrigger schema",
                    "default": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "$id": "#items"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON I want to validate is :

```
{
  "description": "description",
  "requesteeName": "05300005",
  "processOrder": [
  {"cleanHistory": {} },
    {"processEvents": {
      "identityTrigger": "some trigger"
    }}
  ],
  "deleteObjects": "true"
}
```

Now, I'm expecting it to fail when I remove the string:

`"identityTrigger": "some trigger"`

because the **"identityTrigger"** property is in the required array in the processEvents object. But it is not failing, something has to be wrong in the array matching (processOrder array). 
Could someone give me an advice?
Thanks

Comment: If you remove the “identityTrigger” property, that JSON example still validated against the first `anyOf` option as that defines no required properties.

Comment: @Carsten Ok, but so how should I set the schema to make it failing when in the processOrder element I have the processEvent object without the eventTrigger property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the still-successful validation was the fact that the first `anyOf` option did not specify any `required` properties while allowing any `additionalProperties`, therefore an empty JSON Object was always valid against this first option.
The fix is to expect at least one property in each `anyOf` to avoid an empty object being valid against any of them.

However, there seem to be some additional points here that would benefit from clarification:

1. The `additionalProperties` keyword is by default `true` and does not need to be mentioned in that case. As per [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties):

   > The `additionalProperties` keyword is used to control the handling of extra stuff, that is, properties whose names are not listed in the `properties` keyword. By default any additional properties are allowed.
2. The `additionalItems` keyword only applies if `items` is an array (i.e. the array is a tuple of different types at specific positions). As per [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#items):

   > When `items` is a single schema, the `additionalItems` keyword is meaningless, and it should not be used.
3. Your `default` values are empty objects, which are invalid against the described structure with `required` properties. Best to leave those `default` values out as well then – unless that is just because you removed their contents in the scope of this question here to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to understand better how it works, as @Carsten said in the comment the **anyOf** with the single items without required properties was not working because any item with any property would have been validated.
The correct schema would be(in bold the changes):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "urn:jsonschema:testing:frmwk",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "The root schema",
  "default": {},
  "required": [
    "processOrder"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "properties": {
    "processOrder": {
      "$id": "#processOrder",
      "type": "array",
      "title": "The processOrder schema",
      "default": [],
      "additionalItems": false,
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$id": "#0",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The first anyOf schema",
            "default": {},
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "required": ["cleanHistory"],
            "properties": {
              "cleanHistory": {
                "$id": "#cleanHistory",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The cleanHistory schema",
                "default": {},
                "additionalProperties": true,
                "properties": {}
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$id": "#3",
            "type": "object",
            "title": "The fourth anyOf schema",
            "default": {},
            "additionalProperties": true,
            "required": ["processEvents"],
            "properties": {
              "processEvents": {
                "$id": "#processEvents",
                "type": "object",
                "title": "The processEvents schema",
                "default": {},
                "required": [
                  "identityTrigger"
                ],
                "additionalProperties": true,
                "properties": {
                  "identityTrigger": {
                    "$id": "#identityTrigger",
                    "type": "string",
                    "title": "The identityTrigger schema",
                    "default": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "$id": "#items"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the main changes are 2:

1. Added **"additionalItems": false** in the array object definition
2. Added  **"required": ["cleanHistory"]** and  **"required": ["processEvents"]** for each correspondent root properties item, in my case ("cleanHistory" and "processEvents") in this way the AnyOf will force to use one of the schema listed to validate the items in the array.